# Using instanceof to test interfaces

Tags: java, interface, instanceof, implements

I've been having a bit of trouble with this problem. The question:

Write a complete Java program that does the following:

- declares interfaces I1 and I2, both with empty bodies
- declare interface I3 with an empty body, which extends both of the
  above interfaces
- declare interface I4 with an empty body
- class X implements I3 with an empty body
- class W with an empty body implements I4 and extends X
- create a class InstanceofTest that does the following in the main():

  - Create an object w of class W.
  - Use the instanceof operator to test if the object w implements each
    of the interfaces and is of type X, and display the appropriate
    message.

---

So this is what I've come up with so far:

---

```
public interface I1
{

}
```

---

```
public interface I2
{

}
```

---

```
public interface I3 extends I1, I2
{

}
```

---

```
public interface I4
{

}
```

---

```
public class W extends X implements I4
{

}
```

---

I'm having a bit of confusion with the InstanceofTest method. I know that the instanceof operator would tell you if a certain object is an instance of a certain type, like when you do it like this:

---

```
public class InstanceofTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        W w = new W();
        if (w instanceof X)
        {
            System.out.println("w is an instance of X.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

The problem I'm having is using `instanceof` to see if w implements each of the interfaces. I have no idea how I would go about doing that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Edit: So, should I do it like this?

---

```
public class InstanceofTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        W w = new W();
        if (w instanceof X)
        {
            System.out.println("w is an instance of X.");
        }

        if (w instanceof I1)
        {
            System.out.println("w implements I1.");
        }

        if (w instanceof I2)
        {
            System.out.println("w implements I2.");
        }

        if (w instanceof I3)
        {
            System.out.println("w implements I3.");
        }

        if (w instanceof I4)
        {
            System.out.println("w implements I4.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Yep, it seems correct to me your attemps, do you have something wrong with your code?

Comment: Oh no, I'm not saying I'm having any trouble with my following code. I'm just having problems with one of the bullets I have to do:


"Use the instanceof operator to test if the object w implements each of the interfaces and is of type X, and display the appropriate message."

I'm not sure what do to for that.

Comment: `instanceof` can be used with an interface type just as well as for `X`.

Comment: Copy paste your `instanceof` test and substitute `X` for each `interface`. What's the issue?

Comment: Ohh, I had no idea you can use instanceof to check instance types as well. Thanks very much!

Comment: you can get an array of implemented interfaces by using `myObject,getClass().getInterfaces()` and then you can check which item of this array is your desired interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is the full solution for you:

```
public interface I1 {}
```

---

```
public interface I2 {}
```

---

```
public interface I3 extends I1, I2 {}
```

---

```
public interface I4 {}
```

---

```
public class X implements I3 {}
```

---

```
public class W extends X implements I4 {}
```

---

```
public class InstanceofTest {
  public static void main(String[] args){
      W w = new W();

      if (w instanceof I1)
        System.out.println("W implements I1");

      if (w instanceof I2)
        System.out.println("W implements I2");

      if (w instanceof I3)
        System.out.println("W implements I3");

      if (w instanceof I4)
        System.out.println("W implements I4");

      if (w instanceof X)
        System.out.println("W extends X");
    }
}
```

And the result will be that `W` implements every interface and extends `X`.

Comment: Thanks very much, I just figured it out from another comment! Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: FYI posting the full code answers to homework questions is frowned upon. The only reason I'm not downvoting is because the OP says that the answer was already evident _before_ you posted.

Comment: @BoristheSpider posting such an answer is not that big of a deal, it will not hurt anyone and I could possibly gain a small amount of rating. In addition, studying carefully is OP's own business. In this question I see some statements but no real problems or problem explanations, so I just posted the whole solution. For me answering to even relatively small / easy question is a challenge as I study myself by searching for info and testing my own code.

Answer (score -2):

Store those interfaces in `Collection` like `Set<Class> classes`, then iterate over them and compare with your object.

Comment: `instanceof` needs a type name, not an object.  You can't iterate over type names.

Comment: I didn't mean to use an `instanceof` for comparing, I should have stated this in my answer. You can use `interface1.isInstance(w)` (interface is Class object from Set).

Comment: The OP's assignment said he has to use `instanceof`.